# How to change the class on an element using jQuery from a multiple select input

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the class from various div regarding the selected(s) item in a single multi-select form input?

The code I wrote works partially. When I have one option, it's working. As soon I select two options in the input, it doesn't work.

I can't modify or add arguments to the select and div block code. The code is part of a WordPress plugin for which adding extra arguments is complicated.

Here is what I did:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#gd_placecategory').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '220') {
      $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
      $("#stay_categoriescamping_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
      $("#stay_glampingcamping_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
    } else {
      $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
      $("#stay_categoriescamping_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
      $("#stay_glampingcamping_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    }
  });

  $('#gd_placecategory').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '320') {
      $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
    } else {
      $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    }
  });

  $('#gd_placecategory').change(function() {
    if (['215', '221', '22', '217', '216'].includes($(this).val())){
      $("#stay_roomcomfort_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
    } else {
      $("#stay_roomcomfort_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#stay_roomcomfort_row,
#stay_comfortcampingrv_row,
#stay_typecampingrv_row,
#stay_categoriescamping_row,
#stay_glampingcamping_row {
  display:none
}

.ciDirShow {
  display:block!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="gd_placecategory" multiple=""    field_type="multiselect">
    <option title="Apartments" value="215">Apartments</option>
    <option title="Campsites" value="220">Campsites</option>
    <option title="Guesthouses" value="221">Guesthouses</option>
    <option title="Hotels" value="22">Hotels</option>
    <option title="Houses" value="217">Houses</option>
    <option title="Resorts" value="216">Resorts</option>
    <option title="RV Parks" value="320">RV Parks</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>Some HTML here</div>
<div id="stay_facilities_row" class="">Common content</div>
<div id="stay_roomcomfort_row" class="">Content to display when value is 215 or 221 or 22 or 217 or 216</div>
<div id="stay_comfortcampingrv_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220 or 320</div>
<div id="stay_typecampingrv_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220 or 320</div>
<div id="stay_categoriescamping_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220</div>
<div id="stay_glampingcamping_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220</div>
<div id="stay_services_row" class="">Common content</div>
```

Anyone can help to solve this? Thank you very much

Updated single multi-select input for better understanding.

Comment: All the handlers are running when you select from the dropdown. Each one overrides the changes that the other ones make.

Comment: If you have a multi-select, the value is an array of all the chosen objects. Why are you comparing to a string?

Comment: This is not how you compare a variable to multiple values: `$(this).val() == ('215' || '221' || '22' || '217' || '216')` You have to use `['215', '221', '22', '217', '216'].includes($(this).val())`

Comment: Do you have multiple selects, or a single multi-select?

Comment: Please add your HTML and explain what's supposed to happen with each choice.

Comment: I use a single multi-Select. I have a form and I would like to control regarding the category selected some extra form field to display or not. As I can't modify the code of the full form, jQuery is my best option.

Comment: Please add your HTML and explain what's supposed to happen with each choice. Put this information in the question, not a comment.

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Your first `if` says that `#stay_typecampingrv_row` should only show if the value is `220`. The second one says that it should only show if the value is `320`. Which one is correct?

Comment: I will add the HTML. Basically, I want to do this: If item X is selected then show an X DIV, it's another item Y is selected show Y Div, if X and Y are selected then show X and Y div. And of course, if X is unselected, hide the X div.

Comment: Why do you have multiple event handlers for "change" on the same element `$('#gd_placecategory').change(function() {`?

Comment: But that's not what your code does. It has two different cases that both show `#stay_typecampingrv_row`.

Comment: I added the HTML. I am a beginner in using jQuery so that's why I might have several event handlers. I don't know how to combine in one event handler.

Comment: @Barmar  I updated my answer with a code that is working. Do you think I can make it more simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I am here. It's working well on updating the multi-select but it's not working when I selected 2 or more categories.

Updated: I found a solution that works for any case. Maybe there is more simple?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#gd_placecategory').change(function() {
    var selected = $('#gd_placecategory').val();
    
    $("#stay_roomcomfort_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    $("#stay_categoriescamping_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    $("#stay_glampingcamping_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');
    $("#stay_comfortcampingrv_row").removeClass('ciDirShow');

    if (($.inArray('215', selected) != -1) || ($.inArray('22', selected) != -1) || ($.inArray('221', selected) != -1) || ($.inArray('217', selected) != -1) || ($.inArray('216', selected) != -1)) {
        $("#stay_roomcomfort_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
    }
    if ($.inArray('220', selected) != -1) {
        $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
        $("#stay_categoriescamping_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
        $("#stay_comfortcampingrv_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
        $("#stay_glampingcamping_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
    }
    if ($.inArray('320', selected) != -1) {
        $("#stay_typecampingrv_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
        $("#stay_comfortcampingrv_row").addClass('ciDirShow');
    }
   
});
});
```

```css
#stay_roomcomfort_row,
    #stay_comfortcampingrv_row,
    #stay_typecampingrv_row,
    #stay_categoriescamping_row,
    #stay_glampingcamping_row {
      display:none
    }

    .ciDirShow {
      display:block!important
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
      <select id="gd_placecategory" multiple=""    field_type="multiselect">
        <option title="Apartments" value="215">Apartments</option>
        <option title="Campsites" value="220">Campsites</option>
        <option title="Guesthouses" value="221">Guesthouses</option>
        <option title="Hotels" value="22">Hotels</option>
        <option title="Houses" value="217">Houses</option>
        <option title="Resorts" value="216">Resorts</option>
        <option title="RV Parks" value="320">RV Parks</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>Some HTML here</div>
    <div id="stay_facilities_row" class="">Common content</div>
    <div id="stay_roomcomfort_row" class="">Content to display when value is 215 or 221 or 22 or 217 or 216</div>
    <div id="stay_comfortcampingrv_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220 or 320</div>
    <div id="stay_typecampingrv_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220 or 320</div>
    <div id="stay_categoriescamping_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220</div>
    <div id="stay_glampingcamping_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220</div>
    <div id="stay_services_row" class="">Common content</div>
```

What do you think?

Comment: `selected` is an array, not a single number. So `selected == 215` should be `$.inArray(215, selected) != -1`

Comment: Now I see you're checking for that later. Why do you have both kinds of tests?

Comment: @Barmar I updated all with one single type of test and simplified it. Now it works well and it's simple (I think).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought here is to separate the values from the behavior and put in some data attributes to point to a "pair" element.  I used an id selector but it could be a class or a perhaps more complex one.  To do that:

1. Add data attributes to the options for the "paired" element
2. Get all the "selected" options and then toggle a dataset value
3. Used the dataset value in the CSS to add color but it could be a "display" or some other - so now we only have to toggle those values, not classes to show/hide
4. Triggered the change on the select at the start - notice I set Rabbit to selected so it gets a lime color from the CSS

I put the "pair" right in the markup `data-pair` but you could have had an array of name/value pairs also (dictionary)

Updated with a second example that used hard coded values to do basically the same as the other - not fancy but probably can build from this.

```js
$('#gd_placecategory').on('change', function() {
  //toggle them all off
  $('.my-things').find('.ciDirShow')
    .each(function(index, element) {
      element.dataset.toggle = 'off';
    });
  let pairs = [];
  let opt = $(this) // the option(s) selected
  let values = opt.val();
  let selected = $(this).find('option').filter(":selected"); //selected options
  selected.map(function(index, domElement) {
    pairs.push($(this).data("pair"));
  });
  pairs.forEach(function callbackFn(item, index, array) {
    item.forEach(function dbFn(ar, index, array) {
      $(ar)[0].dataset.toggle = 'on';
    });
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
[data-toggle="off"] {
  color: blue;
}

[data-toggle="on"] {
  color: lime;
}

.my-things {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.my-things>div {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I need HTML here</div>
<label for="gd_placecategory">Choose your pets Place:</label>
<select id="gd_placecategory" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="220" data-pair='["#stay_typecampingrv_row","#stay_categoriescamping_row","#stay_glampingcamping_row"]'>Dog</option>
  <option value="320" data-pair='["#stay_typecampingrv_row"]'>Cat</option>
  <option value="215" data-pair='["#stay_roomcomfort_row"]' selected>Rabbit</option>
  <option value="221" data-pair='["#stay_roomcomfort_row"]'>Parrot</option>
  <option value="22" data-pair='["#stay_roomcomfort_row"]'>Goat</option>
  <option value="217" data-pair='["#stay_roomcomfort_row"]'>Sheep</option>
  <option value="216" data-pair='["#stay_roomcomfort_row"]'>Whild Boar</option>
</select>
<div>
  <button id="check" type="button">Get Selected Values</button>
</div>
<div class="my-things">
  <div class="ciDirShow" id="stay_typecampingrv_row" data-choices="['220','320']">Howdy Campers</div>
  <div class="ciDirShow" id="stay_categoriescamping_row" data-choices="['220','320']">Howdy Categories</div>
  <div class="ciDirShow" id="stay_glampingcamping_row" data-choices="['220','320']">Howdy Glampers</div>
  <div class="ciDirShow" id="stay_roomcomfort_row" data-choices="['215','221' , '22', '217' , '216']">Howdy Be Comfortable</div>
</div>
```

No markuo changes:

```js
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
//create app or use one if exists
var myApp = myApp || {};
// add alerts data
myApp.data = {
  wrapClass: 'my-things',
  wrapper: {},
  targetClass: 'ciDirShow',
  targets: {},
  pairs: [{
    id: "stay_facilities_row",
    selector: "#stay_facilities_row",
    target: [],
    showAlways: true
  }, {
    id: "stay_categoriescamping_row",
    selector: "#stay_categoriescamping_row",
    target: ["220"]
  }, {
    id: "stay_comfortcampingrv_row",
    selector: "#stay_comfortcampingrv_row",
    target: ["220", "320"]
  }, {
    id: "stay_glampingcamping_row",
    selector: "#stay_glampingcamping_row",
    target: ["220"]
  }, {
    id: "stay_typecampingrv_row",
    selector: "#stay_typecampingrv_row",
    target: ["220", "320"]
  }, {
    id: "stay_roomcomfort_row",
    selector: "#stay_roomcomfort_row",
    target: ['215', '221', '22', '217', '216']
  }, {
    id: "get_alongwithbears",
    selector: "#get_alongwithbears",
    target: ["9876"]
  }, {
    id: "likes_chickens",
    selector: "#likes_chickens",
    target: ["1111"]
  }, {
    id: "stay_services_row",
    selector: "#stay_services_row",
    target: [],
    showAlways: true
  }]
};
myApp.func = {
  setToggle: function(me, val) {
    me.dataset.toggle = val;
  },
  hideAll: function(event) {
    $(this)
      .each(function(index, element) {
        myApp.func.setToggle(element, "off");
      });
  },
  showAll: function(event) {
    $(this)
      .each(function(index, element) {
        myApp.func.setToggle(element, "on");
      });
  },
  showDefaults: function() {
    let pairs = myApp.data.pairs;
    myApp.data.targets.trigger('show-all');
    let alwaysThese = pairs.filter(function(item) {
      return item.showAlways;
    });

    alwaysThese.forEach(function(el) {
      $(el.selector).trigger('showAll');
    });

    let notAlways = pairs.filter(function(item) {
      return alwaysThese.indexOf(item.id) === -1 && !!$(item.selector).length;
    });
    let all = myApp.data.targets.filter(function(index, el) {
      let pos = alwaysThese.map(function(item) {
        return item.id;
      }).indexOf(el.id);
      return pos === -1;
    });
    all.trigger('hide-all');
  },
  init: function() {
    let pairs = myApp.data.pairs;
    // this is a bit ugly/fragile but no classes on the elements after 
    // the first to we wrap them and add a class
    myApp.data.targets = $("div").not($('#gd_placecategory').parent('div'))
      .addClass(myApp.data.targetClass);
    myApp.data.targets.wrapAll('<div class="' + myApp.data.wrapClass + '"/>');
    myApp.data.wrapper = $('.' + myApp.data.wrapClass);
    // setup event handlers
    myApp.data.targets.on('hide-all', myApp.func.hideAll);
    myApp.data.targets.on('show-all', myApp.func.showAll);
    myApp.data.targets.data('pair', []);
    myApp.func.showDefaults();
    myApp.data.pairs.forEach(function(pair, index, array) {
      let t = $(pair.selector);
      let tEl = t.get(0);
      t.data("pair", pair);
    });
    $('#gd_placecategory').on('change', myApp.func.changeHandler); //.trigger('change');

  },
  changeHandler: function(event) {
    myApp.func.showDefaults();
    let myPairs = [];
    let sel = $(this); // the  select
    let values = sel.val();
    //selected options
    let selected = sel.find('option').filter(":selected");
    let x = selected.map(function(index, opt) {
      myPairs.push($(opt).val());
    });
    //console.log('pairs:', myPairs, 'Count:', myPairs.length);
    if (myPairs.length > 0) {
      myPairs.forEach(function(pair, index, array) {
        //console.log("pair:", pair);
        if (!!pair) {
          myApp.data.pairs.forEach(function(ar, index, array) {
            //console.log('ar:', ar);
            if (ar.target.indexOf(pair) != -1)
              $(ar.selector).trigger('show-all');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

(function($) {
  myApp.func.init();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
[data-toggle="off"] {
  color: blue;
}

[data-toggle="on"] {
  color: lime;
}

.my-things {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px orange;
}

.cheese {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ciDirShow {
  border: solid #aaaaff 1px;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="gd_placecategory" multiple="" field_type="multiselect">
    <option title="Apartments" value="215">Apartments</option>
    <option title="Campsites" value="220">Campsites</option>
    <option title="Guesthouses" value="221">Guesthouses</option>
    <option title="Hotels" value="22">Hotels</option>
    <option title="Houses" value="217">Houses</option>
    <option title="Resorts" value="216">Resorts</option>
    <option title="RV Parks" value="320">RV Parks</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="stay_facilities_row" class="">Common content</div>
<div id="stay_roomcomfort_row" class="">Content to display when value is 215 or 221 or 22 or 217 or 216</div>
<div id="stay_comfortcampingrv_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220 or 320</div>
<div id="stay_typecampingrv_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220 or 320</div>
<div id="stay_categoriescamping_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220</div>
<div id="stay_glampingcamping_row" class="">Content to display when value is 220</div>
<div id="stay_services_row" class="">Common content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's looking more simple like this but I can't modify the code of the select input adding data-pair (unless adding it with jQuery) and the same for the div block, I can't add data-choices. The code is part of a plugin.

Comment: All that is in the markup can be injected from script as well.  IF I get time I will utilize your markup you added after I posted and add a second example.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am trying it but there is an error in this line: `item.forEach(function dbFn(ar, index, array) ` (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined). I can't figure out how to solve it. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: @Stuart66  Made a revision to use a second where you cannot inject initially